# How do I obtain cacheable URLs to Google Drive files?

Tags: http, url, caching, google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive SDK in an HTML5 application to display the user's images. The same images may appear and disappear multiple times on the page, so it's important that they be cached in order to reduce latency when an image is displayed. As far as I can tell, however, the `webContentLink` returned in Google Drive SDK calls is not cacheable; when I set it as a `background-image` using CSS, it triggers an HTTP request for the same image even if it has already been used on the page.

**How do I obtain cacheable URLs to Google Drive files?**

A workaround I'm using now that seems to work properly is to use the file's `thumbnailLink` and inject a custom size parameter into it; unlike `webContentLink`, `thumbnailLink` appears to be cacheable. This solution feels very hacky and brittle, though.

Comment: You could store the data manually in a javascript-based database. But it seems to me that you're better off using thumbnailLink, because then you're getting the images at the size you want (instead of having users download a super-high-resolution image which is resized to a 16x16 icon on the page)

Comment: I don't want the thumbnails - I want the full-size images; that's why I'm currently manipulating the thumbnail link to provide a full-size image. Even then, thumbnail links are only useful for images, not for audio content (which I'm also downloading).

Comment: In that case I stay with my original suggestion. This should help you get started: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/